# opencv 2.4.2 findContours causes stack overflow

Tags: opencv

I tried running the example program from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) in Windows, using VS 2010, but it keeps giving me a Stack Overflow error. I am using OpenCV 2.4.2 The same code works well on OpenCV 2.3.1.

I am not sure where I am going wrong. I built OpenCV from source and am linking in the libraries dynamically. Can you help?

Comment: Finally a question about stack overflow on stack overflow!

Comment: we can't guess what's going wrong without some evidence about where the stack overflows. try to debug the code and give us the relevant lines of code.

Comment: @Kamyar - it is the line with findContour() that is causing the overflow. I am sorry - I thought that it was obvious from the title...

Comment: I've run the code myself and I can see no stack-overflows, but my guess would be that are you passing the arguments when running the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. These to links [here](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2218) and [here](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2358) show the cause of your problem.

Simply uncheck `OPENCV_CAN_BREAK_BINARY_COMPATIBILITY` when building opencv.